# Android DB and List view design

Tags: android, list, listview, view

I have list of fruit information **i.e.** fruit names. One fruit is correspond with another list **i.e.** vitamin, colour which is correspond with details information of the fruit **i.e.** what vitamin it contains, what is the image of the fruit). Now from this page it will navigate some other information (i.e. if user has been eaten today or not).

So the problem I'm facing is what shall I consider when I design the data structure.

## First page:

```
Apple 
Orange
```

## Second page:

```
Pink
Vitamic 
Image
```

Each item in this page is correspond with specific information of previous page item, here just showing example information for Apple

## Third page

```
Apple-> I have eaten today | I have not eaten today
```

User will be allowed to see the third page with corresponding to first page item. For example. If you mark that you ate apple today, then it update the third page as "eaten", but if you did not eat apple today then it should not be shown. So basically each fruit item correspond with if user has been eaten or not.

Please suggest me how shall I design my DB and list view structure? is that one row item will corresponding with one table.  Please share me any tutorial or sample code. Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried reading any elementary tutorial about designing databases?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, Well I'm not asking for sample code or solve my problem. I just want to learn what approach can be the best & suitable to solve this kinda problem. And no question is dumb, it just depend on the person skills & experience :(

Answer (score 2):

The design that comes to mind is using ORM in your application. This type of data access will allow you to easily store and retrieve objects in your code. You can download OrmLite, a ORM library here: http://ormlite.com/releases/

Following this tutorial: http://sourabhsaldi.blogspot.ca/2012/10/ormlite-tutorial.html, you should create a class and annotate any fields that you need to store, like so:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "fruit")
public class Fruit {
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "_id", generatedId = true)
    private long _id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "color")
    private String color;

    ...
}
```

Then create a class that extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper and setup the database following the instructions in the tutorial.

Then create an adapter for your ListView to use the objects that are stored in your local database. This tutorial should help you do this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html